# How To Manage Response From Task Node With Slow Internet?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I access My Task node in Main Scene Like below.

```
m.Response = CreateObject("roSGNode", "TaskNodeFile")
m.Response.control = "RUN"
```

And Task node Code Like below.

```
sub init()
   ?"init() - Start"
   readdata = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")

   data = "http://Domain:Port" 
   readdata.setUrl(data)

   readdata.SetMinimumTransferRate(1, 75)

   ? "data is " data
   m.port = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
   readdata.setport(m.port)
   readdata.gettostring()
   readdata.SetRequest("POST")

   request = readdata.AsyncPostFromString(data) 
   ?"request : " request
   while (true)
      msg = Wait(3000, m.port) 'Here It's Crashed. I also tried with the 0 MilliSecond. " It's Give a Execution Time Out 
      statusCode = msg.GetResponseCode() 
      if (Type(msg) = "roUrlEvent")
         statusCode = msg.GetResponseCode()
         headers = msg.GetResponseHeaders()
         if msg.getresponsecode() = 200 then
            Response = msg.getstring()
            headers = msg.getresponseheadersarray()
            ?"Response : " Response
            exit while
         else
            m.top.isError = "true"
            m.readdata.asynccancel()
            exit while
         end if
      else
         ? "wait for data"
      end if
      end while
end sub
```

Here the issue is: I tested this Code with 2 Roku premiere+ devices.

- In 1st Device Internet Speed: **10mbps** and
- In 2nd Device Internet Speed: **50mbps**.

I checked My API Response using the Postman tool :

- With 10mbps: **It takes an 1800 MilliSeconds**
- With 50mbps: **It takes a 350 MilliSeconds**

In My Case With 10 Mbps, The Application crashed with this line msg = Wait(3000, m.port). Here, I also tried with the 0 MilliSeconds. After also It's Crashed and Gives Execution Timeout. If Some Internet issues, It's no waiting. It's Directly Crashed. Does anyone Found Good solutions or How to handle this Scenario?.

Comment: But your URL has a space in it?

Comment: Yes, Sorry, Here I Written ":P" so It automatically considered a Smiley Tongue. Now I edited My Post.

Comment: Ok, and why are you doing a GetToString()  and ignoring the results??